# How to build a Flutter app with different icons depending on --dart-define parameter

Tags: flutter

I am using a `--dart-define=myEnv=production` parameter to define the app environment for build. (this is not the same as `--release` or `--debug` flutter build arguments).

**When building with the `--dart-define=myEnv=prod` parameter, I need to have one application icon, and for build with a different value of `myEnv` variable or without this variable, I need to have another app icon.**

I am not using any third-party libraries for the icon.

My Android icons are stored in the path: `android/app/src/main/res`

And iOS icons are stored in the path: `ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset`

I just want to put the second icons on different paths, and in the `Info.plist` and `AndroidManifest.xml` files indicate something like:

```
...
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>$myEnv/icon.png</string>
...
```

```
    <application
        tools:replace="android:label,android:theme"
        android:name=".Application"
        android:label="MyCoolApp"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        android:icon=$myEnv/"@mipmap/launcher_icon">
...
```

Comment: I am trying to do something similar - Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 5):

there are some steps to do that:

Prescription:

- I will provide example when I use 3 env (I use variable like that: `--dart-define=ENV_FLUTTER_IMG_SUFFIX=_dev` to make that little bit laconic but you could use your own variables
- don't use `.` (dot) in name, android has some problem with that

1. get your variables inside native code if you haven't made that yet ([Flutter --dart-define](https://itnext.io/flutter-1-17-no-more-flavors-no-more-ios-schemas-command-argument-that-solves-everything-8b145ed4285d))
2. create 3 sets of ios icons with names where second part is value of your variable (example for `_dev`, `_stage` and empty (for prod))
   [Ios icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uig3k.png)
3. create 3 sets of android icons with names where second part is value of your variable (example for `_dev`, `_stage` and empty (for prod))
   [Android Icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBIZZ.png)
4. go to you project in Xcode, go to **target** -> **Build Settings** -> find `Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name`
5. change `AppIcon` to `AppIcon$(ENV_FLUTTER_IMG_SUFFIX)`
6. got to `./android/app/src/build.gradle`
7. add to your `defaultConfig` 2 (if you want to use round icon too) or 1 new variable:

```
resValue "string", "img_name", "@mipmap/ic_launcher$dartEnvironmentVariables.ENV_FLUTTER_IMG_SUFFIX"
resValue "string", "img_round_name", "@mipmap/ic_launcher_round$dartEnvironmentVariables.ENV_FLUTTER_IMG_SUFFIX"
```

8. go to `./android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`
9. change your icons defines to

```
android:icon="@string/img_name"    
android:roundIcon="@string/img_round_name"
```